# How can I delete Microsoft Account (formerly Windows Live ID) automatically?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-live, microsoft-store

I'm looking for a way to delete accounts I've previously logged in with automatically with a script. I'm having trouble searching for the cache location of them. I've looked in multiple different places, tried searching in regedit,
Get-LocalUser returns local users, but not the Microsoft Ones,
Deleted all of them from Credential Manager, still nothing.
I've even looked into various old threads from 2011 with no success.

I'm using Windows 10 machine.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

[Emails & accounts page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4bnT.png)